# time_point extension to a struct holding another member

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I have a struct consisting of a `string` and a `time_point`, and I want it to exhibit behavior similar to `std::time_point` in C++20 with minimal code, without explicitly defining all comparison operators.
How can I achieve this?

My code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

struct MyStruct {
    std::string name;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time;

    // Comparison operators
    bool operator==(const MyStruct& other) const {
        return time == other.time;
    }

    bool operator!=(const MyStruct& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    bool operator<(const MyStruct& other) const {
        return time < other.time;
    }

    bool operator<=(const MyStruct& other) const {
        return time <= other.time;
    }

    // Prefix increment operator
    MyStruct& operator++() {
        ++time;
        return *this;
    }

    // Postfix increment operator
    MyStruct operator++(int) {
        MyStruct temp = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return temp;
    }
    // and so on...
};
```

Comment: Just fyi, `operator++()` is going to add a platform-specific amount of time to `MyStruct`.  On Linux it will add 1ns.  On Windows it will add 100ns.  And on macOS it will add 1000ns (1us).  This may be what you want.  But if it isn't, you can fix this by making `time` a specific precision of your choosing.  E.g. `std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds> time;`.  With that change, `operator++()` adds 1ns on all platforms.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, thank you for your comment,  I'm using linux and I will inherit from time_point as suggested by Christian Stieber. I didn't do it because I thought it was an Undefined Behavior

Comment: My comment still applies to the inheritance design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just **make** your struct a time_point?

```
struct MyStruct : public std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
{
    std::string name;
};
```

Aside from that, there is really no shame in acknowledging that your `MyStruct` merely **has** a `time` member, and just perform the operations on that one directly. Whichever fits the actual context better: is your `MyStruct` actually a `time_point` with a name, or does it just tell us the birthday of some guy?

Comment: The correct thing to do is look at each member a time point has and think whether it makes sense for MyStruct. Looking at how the question is formulated, probably yes.

Comment: @anatolyg, I run into an issue. If I call the operator++ and lose the information about string

Comment: @TedZach yeah, some operators create new objects, and they'll only create the objects of their class, without taking derived classes into account. My bad to forget about that -- I rarely need this kind of construct, and when I do I generally don't care if some operators are not 100% out of the box...

Answer (score 2):

In C++20, instead of 6 comparison operators, you only need to define `operator==` and `operator<=>` (aka *spaceship operator*):

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::string name;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time;

    // Comparison operators
    bool operator==(const MyStruct& other) const {
        return time == other.time;
    }
    auto operator<=>(const MyStruct& other) const {
        return time <=> other.time;
    }
```

All other comparison operators (<,>,<=,>=,!=) will be generated from these two.

However, there is no C++20-specific magic for other operators (`operator++` etc.)

Comment: thank you. I need other operators too. ++, -- etc.